# What inspired Edgar Rice Burroughs' African characters in his Tarzan novels?

Tags: tarzan, tarzan-of-the-apes

Since Edgar Rice Burroughs never went to Africa,  what inspired his African characters, such as the Waziri tribes and Chief Muviro?

> "I want to write of distant places," I confessed to Mr. Burroughs,
> "but I've never traveled and they tell me one should never attempt to
> write about lands he has never seen."
>
> "Well," he said, with a smile, "most of my stories are laid in Africa,
> and I've never been there."
>
> <sub><sup>[An Interview With Edgar Rice Burroughs in Which He Frankly
> Discusses His Methods and Gives Sound Advice](https://www.erbzine.com/mag0/0059.html)</sup></sub>

Comment: Good question. For that matter, I wonder what inspired his Martian characters, I don't believe he's been there either.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding in a quote confirming that he'd never been to Africa

Comment: Martian is a different story they could be imagined any how and his Mars book was inspired by the works of Percival Lowell

Comment: Actually @Kevinyoka "Martian" wasn't really *"all"* that different for him and the vast majority of his readers when you think about it, very few indeed of his readers at that time would have had any direct experience of Africa so he could probably have made up just about anything he liked for much the same reasons that he could do that with Mars, namely that few enough of his readers as not too matter could contradict anything he chose to write, consider when he wrote and who he wrote for, it's not exactly the same of course but the difference lies only in the degree to which he could do that

Answer (score 3):

Burroughs was a voracious reader and had his own library of titles from which he drew inspiration. He also spent a great deal of time in the Chicago library...

> ...studying the accounts and illustrations compiled by the early
> explorers who had studied the Africa of the earlier Victorian era [including]
> [Paul Du Chaillu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Du_Chaillu) and [J. W. Buel](https://www.librarything.com/author/bueljamesw)...
>
> <sub><sup>[ERBZine - #39](https://www.erbzine.com/mag39/3913.html)</sup></sub>

[image]

Notable works in [his own personal archive](https://www.erbzine.com/mag12/1262.html) include;

- *In Brightest Africa* by Carl E. Akeley
- *Heroes of the Dark Continent or How Stanley Found Emin Pasha* by J. W. Buel
- *Gorilla: Tracking and Capturing The Great Ape-Man of Africa [Big Game Hunting in  - British East Africa and The Congo]* by Ben Burbridge
- *In Savage Africa* by Verney Lovett Cameron
- *Adventures of an African Slaver* by Theodore Canot
- *In African Forests and Jungle* by Paul Du Chaillu
- *The Seven Wonders of South Africa* by Hedley Arthur Chilvers
- *Lost in the Jungle: Narrated for Young People* by Paul Du Chaillu
- *Silent Highways of the Jungle* by G. M. Dyott, editor
- *The Wild Beasts of the World* by Frank Finn
- *In Savage Africa* by E.J. Glave
- *The Mad Mullah of Somaliland* by Douglas James Jardine
- *In the Land of the Lion* by Cherry Kearton
- *In the Wilds of Africa: A Tale for Boys* by W. H. G. Kingston
- *Memories of an African Hunter* by Denis D. Lyell
- *The White African: The Story of Mafavuke, "who dies and lives again"* by George Albert Wilder
- *Adventures in Swaziland* by Owen Rowe O'Neil
- *The Man-Eaters of Tsavo: and Other East African Adventures* by Lieutenant-Colonel J. H. Patterson
- *The Book of the Lion* by Sir Alfred E. Pease
- *Beyond the Utmost Purple Rim: Abyssinia, Somaliland, Kenya Colony, Zanzibar, the Camoros, Madagascar* by Edward Alexander Powell
- *In Barbary, Tunisia, Algeria, Morocco and the Sahara* by Edward Alexander Powell
- *The Map that is Half Unrolled* by Edward Alexander Powell
- *Captured by Zulus: A Story of Trapping In Africa* by Harry Prentice
- *Captured by Apes or How Philip Garland became King of Apeland* by Harry Prentice
- *In Darkest Africa, or the Quest Rescue and Retreat of Emin Governor of Equatoria* by Henry M. Stanley
- *Horning Into Africa* by W. S. "Woody" Van Dyke
- *Jungle Trails and Jungle People* by Casper Whitney
- *Among Pygmies and Gorillas with the Swedish Zoological Expedition to Central Africa 1921* by Prince William of Sweden
- *Living Africa: A Geologist's Wanderings Through the Rift Valleys* by Bailey Willis
- *Marching on Tanga* by F. Brett Young
- *Savages* by F. Brett Young